# gethostname() returns accurate hostname, bind() doesn't like it

Tags: python, socketserver

Doing a python socket tutorial, entire codebase is as follows

```
import socket as so

s = so.socket()

host = so.gethostname()
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
```

and error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 13, in <module>
    s.bind((host, port))
  File "/Users/solid*name*/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Printing hostname gives me

```
super*name*
```

Which is, in fact, my computer's hostname, although I feel like there should be '.local' at the end of it. In fact, s.bind() works if there is a .local at the end. Why isn't it there?

Mac OS X 10.7.5, Python 2.7.6 :: Anaconda 2.0.0 (x86_64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`socket` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> If you use a hostname in the *host* portion of IPv4/v6 socket address, the program may show a nondeterministic behavior, as Python uses the first address returned from the DNS resolution. The socket address will be resolved differently into an actual IPv4/v6 address, depending on the results from DNS resolution and/or the host configuration. For deterministic behavior use a numeric address in *host* portion.

The typical way of binding sockets is to just bind to *all* network interfaces, using either of the equivalent host specifications `''` or `'0.0.0.0'` (for IPv4).  This is equivalent to the C constant `INADDR_ANY`:

```
s.bind(('', port))
```

And then you don't have to worry about hostnames or current network interface addresses etc.  Only in the more unusual case of wanting to bind to a particular network interface (e.g. on a host with multiple NICs) should you ever need to specify the address in the call to `bind()`; in that case, you need to figure out the numeric IP address of the network interface you want and pass that.